# Combining citations for two different sets of authors with Natbib when they share a common lead author

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I use natbib and bibtex.  I have 2 different articles as follows:

```
Article 1- Written by authors A, B, C, and D in year 2000.
Article 2- Written by authors A, C, E, and G in year 2003.
```

I want to refer to these 2 articles in the text.  I would say something like A et al. (2000, 2003) but I know that is not precise since technically they are 2 different sets of authors.  In reality, I only care about referencing the first author in something like Author A and collagues in 2000 and 2003.  However, because I use hyperreferencing, natbib, and bibtex, I still want it to be the case that when I click on the 2000 in the .pdf, it takes me to the bibliographic information in the reference section for the 2000 article and the same with the 2003 one.

I use natbib.  Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you've set up the bib entries in question along the following lines:

```
@article{ABCD:2000,
    author = "Andersen, A. and B. Beckham and C. Christiansen and D. Dawkins",
    year = 2000,
    ...
}
@article{ACEG:2003,
    author = "Andersen, A. and C. Christiansen and E. Eglund and G. Gustafsson",
    year = 2003,
    ...
}
```

If you cite these entries using `natbib`'s `\citet` command, as in

```
\citet{ABCD:2000,ACEG:2003)
```

you would indeed get something like

```
Andersen et al. (2000, 2003)
```

I'd venture the guess that the risk of creating the impression among your readers that all co-authors of A. Andersen in both publications are the same is rather minimal. However, if you think the risk is non-negligible, you could take one or more of the following measures.

- You could use the variant citation command `\citet*`, which will print the full list of authors' surnames.
- You could load the `natbib` package with the `longnamesfirst` option. That way, the first time you cite these two entries, the full list rather than the abbreviated list of surnames will be generated automatically when you use `\citet` or `\citep` on these entries.
- If that's still not enough, you could define "citation aliases", as in

  ```
  \defcitetalias{ABCD:2000}{ABCD}
  \defcitetalias{ACEG:2003}{ACEG}
  ```

  The citation command `\citetalias{ABCD:2000,ACEG:2003}` will then generate `ABCD, ACEG`. By the way, when using citation aliases, it's usually a good idea to introduce them explicitly, as in

  ```
  ...as argued by `\citet*{ABCD:2000}, hereafter abbreviated as \citetalias{ABCD:2000}, ...
  ```